# spark dataframe to csv in S3

Tags: python, pyspark, boto3

I need to upload a spark dataframe as a csv to a path in S3.
I'm having some trouble to find a solution whithout using some libraries.

Due to client limitations, i cannot use pandas or s3fs. I can use boto3.

Here's what a i have:

```
import datetime as dt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import boto3

MY_BUCKET = spark.confi.get('spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_BUCKET')

df = spark.sql("selec column_1, column_2 from my table")

date = dt.date.today()

file_date = date.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
```

I managed to build a csv-like object using df.collect() and iterating over it.
(for row in df.collect()...)

Now i need to save df as csv to a specfic path in S3 like:

```
MY_BUCKET+"/folder/filename"+file_date+".csv"
```

I solved this using both pandas and s3fs, but the final version must only use python and boto3.

Spark functions like df.write.csv() do not solved the problem, as spark creates another folder or doesn't allow me to proper edit the file name.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You most probably need to two things. First, you have to save DataFrame into a single file, preferably to some *temp* location:

```py
temp_location = MY_BUCKET+"/folder/temp/"
df.coalesce(1).write.csv(temp_location)
```

Then, using Boto3, you have to extract this single CSV file from temp location into the preferred destination, and rename it at the same time. It seems like `Boto3` already includes a method [`copy_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object) which should allow you to do so.

**Note**: it seem like `Boto3` doesn't allow you to use wildcards when specifying the object names which should be copied, so you will have to get the exact name of the single CSV file in the *temp* location, using Boto3.

Comment: I did, actually.  
df.write  creates another folder, like:

/folder/filename_file_date.csv/file.csv

Comment: I've updated my response accordingly. I don't know the exact commands you need to use from Boto3, so I just described what next steps will be useful for you :)

Comment: I managed to solve this using boto3, it took me some time though. Here's how:


`s3 = boto3.cliente('s3')`

`s3.put_object(Bucket=MY_BUCKET, Body=bytes(data, encoding='utf-8', Key="folder/filename"+file_date+".csv")`

Comment: This was possible because i saved data as as a resulting string from df.collect()
`data = "column1;column_2"
for row in df.collect():
    data+=str(row['column_1'])+';'+str(row['column_2'])+'\n'`

Then i used data as the value for the Body parameter.

I apreciate the help and the time you took to answer my question, thank you =)